# Mysql generate this type of query for get result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table "code"

```
code    price
10***   10
11***   11
12***   12
13***   13
100**   100
112**   110
```

1. Search code "11220" will return price "110"
2. Search code "11201" will return price "11"

then how to generate this type of query?

Comment: This can better be done in an imperative language that makes limited calls to simpler SQL. Building this in the declarative SQL language is not going to be easy or straightforward.

Comment: Can you explain why searching for code "11201" will return price "11"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain much in your question but maybe you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT price
  FROM code
 WHERE '11220' LIKE REPLACE(code, '*', '_')
 ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(code, '*', '')) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
| PRICE |
|-------|
|   110 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc9eb/3)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Use query like this

```
SELECT  price FROM code where code = "your search value";
```

OR

```
 SELECT price FROM code WHERE code LIKE 'your search value%';
```